# mysql data being inserted twice via php

Tags: php, mysql

I can't for the life of me figure out why this function is causing multiple entries into my database table...

When I run the function I end up with two records stacked on top of each one second apart

[screen cap http://img132.imageshack.us/img132/5053/screenshot20100517at259.png](http://img132.imageshack.us/img132/5053/screenshot20100517at259.png)

here is the function:

```
function generate_signup_token(){
    $connection = new DB_Connect(); // <--- my database connection class
    $ip = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); 
    $sign_up_token = uniqid(mt_rand(), true);
    $_SESSION['signup_token'] = $sign_up_token;
    $sign_up_token = mysql_real_escape_string($sign_up_token);
    $query = "INSERT INTO `token_manager` (`ip_address`, `signup_token`) VALUES ('$ip', '$sign_up_token')";
    mysql_query($query);
}

generate_signup_token();
```

Comment: I'd suspect a double insert or duplicate request...

Comment: Is this the only place in the code where you call `generate_signup_token()`?

Comment: I'm definitely only calling the function once.  If I remove it, nothing happens.

Comment: Do you have some sort of automatic page refreshing or redirection that might cause two requests to be made?

Comment: @Mark, I'm running this backtrace function... and my page only reloads if it finds a cookie that signifies a logged in user, otherwise it just loads once and fires this function to track if they decide to sign up...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest piece of evidence that this function is being called more than once is the different signup tokens that are being generated.

Also, there is a one second difference between inserts which may be indicative of multiple page requests. If there is consistently such a time disparity, I'd investigate the access log. If there's only one page request, then the function must be called more than once somehow.

Comment: I wish I could give you both the right answer check.. I threw in a die(); function after I called the function and it indeed inserted just one record in the DB.  I'll have to go rethink my whole action list now...

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your function is fine. It appears that you are somehow calling the function twice. I'd suggest adding some debugging information to the function to figure out why. The function [debug_print_backtrace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) might come in handy for this.

Comment: this is my result:
#0 generate_signup_token() called at [/home/hupcap/public_html/mydomain.com/index.php:19] 
I'm assuming that's just once?

Comment: @Jascha: I think it's being called once per request. Check your web server logs to see how many requests there are.

Comment: yeah, I gave webbiedave the chck mark for the access log comment, I greatly appreciate your pointing out this debug function for me.